# Bootstrap/Flask modal Bad Request for Post

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I am trying to get the contents of a modal input form with `Flask` and `Boostrap`. Most of the other responses for similar questions on SO talk about adding the path for `form action`, but that isn't solving this one. What is causing the issue here?

init.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "Some secret string here"
@app.route('/getname', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def getname():

    if request.method == "POST":
        print request.form['value of Id']
    return render_template("done.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

html modal form:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="post" role="form" action="/getname">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Name" class="control-label">Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name">

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <a href="/getname"><button type="submit" id="btnUpdate" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button></a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form method="post" role="form" action="/getname" id="form1">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Name" class="control-label">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
</form>
<button type="submit" id="btnUpdate" class="btn btn-primary" form="form1">Submit</button>
```

It seems you have mislocated your button, try this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the name attribute instead of the id. That is not something specific to Flask or even Python, but HTTP instead.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "Some secret string here"
@app.route('/getname', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def getname():

    if request.method == "POST":
        print request.form['Name']
    return render_template("done.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and

```
<form method="post" role="form" action="/getname" id="form1">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Name" class="control-label">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" name="Name">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
</form>
<button type="submit" id="btnUpdate" class="btn btn-primary" form="form1">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thanks!! I also missed "name" field and your above solution solved the problem.